# If two people stand on opposite ends of the earth and pull a rope tightly, will the rope cut through the Earth?

Tags: geometry, space, topology, geodesics

I'm reading about how a "straight line" depends on the geometry of space. While I *think* I understand this, the example people give is:

"Imagine a straight line on earth connecting two cities. It's actually curved because the earth is curved".

My response to that would be "Well no, because a *truly* straight line would cut through the earth. Like a straight string would cut through an apple".

So question: If two people took an infinitely strong and light string, stood on opposite ends of the earth, and pulled almost infinitely tightly, would the string curve around the earth a few feet above, or would it cut through to the core?

Comment: Yes it would cut. You're quibbling about the meaning of "straight". Does it mean straight in Euclidean 3-space, or a geodesic on a surface, like the surface of the Earth. Most people don't know the word "geodesic", but that's what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

What this example is trying to point out is that in a 2 dimension space like the surface of a sphere, 'straight' lines are meaningless and the shortest path in this case is called 'geodesic'. If you try to 'pull the rope' and 'cut' the earth' as you mentioned, then you are in a 3d Euclidean space which is not the case in this example.

Comment: So the string would indeed cut through the earth, and not curve around it?

Comment: No, the cutting takes place at center but not at ends. For central parts normal force will  get an efficient maximum cut. Strong steel cable and soft earth cut up to  some depth like a crescent and no cutting takes place at antipodal points. But yes, if the rope is *full *circumference (40,000 km) and when  the two guys are side by side exerting forces in opposite directions  it will cut all around as a full circle while shrinking. Try putting  a string around a rasgulla, and pulling it.It is assumed we are on great circles.